# Multicolumn Dropdown in Ultragrid

Tags: .net, vb.net, infragistics, ultrawingrid

I have to do some maintenance on an VB.NET application (Visual Studio 2012) that uses `Infragistics`.

I need to modify column in an existing `UltraGrid` control. One of the column is already a `dropdown` and now it should be changed to `Multicolumn` dropdown, allowing the selection from a list of values.

I modified the column, and now i'm thinking what to be set in the the Style?. I created a `ValueList` and assigned it to the new column.

How to achieve this?

**Note**: I tried like setting the type as `dropdown` and binding the `valuelist` but it shows only the first `column` in the `dropdown` which is retrieved in the result.

Comment: Rather than using a ValueList, you can use the UltraDropDown to provide a multi-column drop down.  This is used by setting the ValueList property of the column to the UltraDropDown instance.  See help for more details: http://help.infragistics.com/NetAdvantage/WinForms/Current/CLR4.0/?page=WinDropDown_About_WinDropDown.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you need to use a UltraCombo, not a ValueList. This is an example on how to do it, but lacks of many details like how to retrieve the values from a datatable that you need to supply

```
private Sub grid_InitializeLayout(object sender, InitializeLayoutEventArgs e) Handles InitializeLayout
    Dim yourTable As DataTable = GetYourDataTable()
    Dim combo = new UltraCombo()
    combo.DataSource = yourTable
    combo.DisplayMember = "Field_name_To_Display"
    combo.ValueMember = "Field_name_that_binds_combo_table_To_grid_Column"
    ' Now supposing the column that needs the combo is the first one of your grid
    e.Layout.Bands(0).Columns(0).ValueList = combo
End Sub
```

Comment: What is the style type should i use to set for the column?

Comment: That depends if you want the combo to be editable or just a selection list (Dropdown, DropdownWithList etc).... Answer updated to show that also the DisplayMember and ValueMember properties should be set to correctly bind the Combo datatable with the lookup column

Comment: @Sandy if you were using a ValueList before you may want to consider using the UltraDropDown which implements IValueList and you can set the instance of the UltraDropDown to your column's ValueList property like you are already doing with the ValueList.

Comment: @Steve: When I try to bind it to the datasource of the ultracombo it throws "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: @Steve: I'm binding a collection which returns 2 rows to the ultracombo.

Comment: @Steve: Its working fine steve. thanks. One question is do we have to dispose the object after the process?

Comment: The grid should dispose the UltraCombo when you close the form because it has a reference to the added control. Not really sure, need to check

Comment: @Steve: When I try to dispose the object in 'finally' block it throws 'Object reference error'. any solutions?

Comment: @Steve: Can you help me in this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16854159/dropdown-should-show-only-the-display-member

Comment: @Steve: Can you help me in this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17042149/format-ultragridrow-cells