# Format UltragridRow Cells

Tags: vb.net, infragistics, ultrawingrid

I need to format the cell of an `UltraGrid`.

Like: Making the cell to format a `DateTime`.

I have done for a column,

```
   UltraGridColumn.Format = "d"
```

likewise is there any option to format individual cells?

```
UltraGridRow.Cells("abc")= ?
```

**Note:** Using the Infragistics version 12.1

Comment: What version r you using?

Comment: Could you explain why you need to format a single cell differently from the Whole column?

Comment: No steve i'm selecting a particular row from a grid and showing the details in another grid. Since the grid has two columns like Name and value I have to do it for a single cell. The value part now contains the DateTime and I have to format it and the other cells have different values. Can u get me?

Comment: @Steve:Can we format? Is there any option?

Comment: I am not sure, but every cell has a property called Editor representing the embedded control used to handle the cell value. This Editor property has a DateFilter property that you can use to format the values going from the datasource to the editor and viceversa. Probably this is the way to follow but, as have said I am not sure if you could obtain the result required

Comment: But I have to validate for many datatypes according to the values. What can I do?

Comment: @Sandy the approach that Steve is suggesting setting the Editor on a cell by cell basis is correct (or you could set the EditorComponent).  As far as how to do this based on the type, you could handle initialize row and check the type of the object stored in the cell and set the editor based on the type.  If you do this you could create a dictionary where you use Type as the key so that you could reuse editors when you have multiple values of the same type.  There is also a sample in the installed samples that you can reference.  Feature Browser -> WinGrid -> WinGrid Samples Explorer.

Comment: Once the samples explorer is open select V3 per Cell ValueList and Editors.  You can also open the C# or VB solution from the feature browser.  If you don't already have the samples installed you can install them by running the platform installer again.

Comment: @alhalama: Kindly help on this question please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17312414/standard-formatting-vs-custom-formatting-in-ultragridcells

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick to force the UltraGrid to use different editors for cells in the same column is based on a set of programming objects and patterns offered by the infrastructure of the control.

The first thing is to consider is the `InitializeRow` event. This event is called for each row when you set the initial DataSource of the grid or when you change something in the underlying DataSource. You can differentiate between the two situations thanks to the `e.Reinitialize` flag. If it is false, then the whole datasource is applied to the grid, if it is true then only a subset of rows are reinitialized usually because the user has edited the cell or the code has changed a value in the datasource.

The second thing to consider is the `Editor` property present in every UltraGridCell or UltraGridColumn. It is an object that is built automatically by the UltraGrid to allow the cell editing. The UltraGrid code set this object based on the datatype of the column and, obviously, sets the same editor for every cell of the column. You could set your own editor at the column level (usually in the `InitializeLayout` event) or on cell by cell basis looking at your formatting rule.

Let's try an example (Big parts of this is taken from the example code suggested in its comments by Alhalama)

Suppose you have a DataTable with only two columns: 
First column is called `CONDITION` and contains a string. This string is my formatting requirement.
The second column is called `DATEINFO` and contains the dates that should be formatted differently accordingly to the value in the column CONDITION.
So if `CONDITION = 'TEST1'` then the DATEINFO cell is formatted with Day/Month/Year pattern, if the `CONDITION='TEST2'` then the DATEINFO cell should be formatted with Hour/Minute/Seconds.

```
private void ultraGrid1_InitializeRow(object sender, InitializeRowEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.ReInitialize == false)
   {
       DefaultEditorOwnerSettings editorSettings;
       DateTimeEditor datetime_editor;
       string condition = e.Row.GetCellValue("Condition").ToString();
       switch (condition)
       {
            case "TEST1":
                editorSettings = new DefaultEditorOwnerSettings()
                editorSettings.DataType = typeof(DateTime);
                editorSettings.MaskInput = "mm/dd/yyyy";
                datetime_editor = new DateTimeEditor(new DefaultEditorOwner(editorSettings));
                e.Row.Cells["DateInfo"].Editor = datetime_editor;
                break;
            case "TEST2":
                editorSettings = new DefaultEditorOwnerSettings()
                editorSettings.DataType = typeof(DateTime);
                editorSettings.MaskInput = "hh:mm:ss";
                datetime_editor = new DateTimeEditor(new DefaultEditorOwner(editorSettings));
                e.Row.Cells["DateInfo"].Editor = datetime_editor;
                break;
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Why not? It is generic, of course the Editor type to build should be consistent with the underlying datatype (EditorWithText, ColorPickerEditor, FontNameEditor, EditorWithMask, EditorWithCombo, OptionSetEditor, CheckEditor) Open the example linked by Alhalama and search for frmCellValueList.cs form/designer

Comment: No `d` is not a valid format expression for dates (or at least is not recognized by the UltraGridCell)

Comment: This worked perfectly for me, thanks!  @Santhosh I know it's been a while, but you can use `EditorWithText` for currency and decimal values (instead of `DateTimeEditor`).